# Display Text in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I want to display text according tenderId persent in tender_partial table if (j==str) then status of tender column display  "On hold" else Not on hold.   in label whose id is lblstat in gridview in template field.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
       string j=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(); 
       SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select TenderId from Tender_Partial where TenderId=" + j,con); 
       SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); 
       while(dr.Read()) { 
           string id2 = dr["TenderId"].ToString();
           if (j == id2) // here where i get value j equals to id2 then 
           { 
             status="On Hold"; 
             status=Gridview1.row[8].cell[8].Findcontrol("lblstats").tostring(); 
           }
           else {
             status=" Not On Hold";
             status=Gridview1.row[8].cell[8].Findcontrol("lblstats").tostring();
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried?

Comment: ya for sure: for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) { string j=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(); SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select TenderId from Tender_Partial where TenderId=" + j,con); SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); while(dr.Read()) { string id2 = dr["TenderId"].ToString(); if (j == id2) // here where i get value j equals to id2 then { status="On Hold"; status=Gridview1.row[8].cell[8].Findcontrol("lblstats").tostring(); } else { status=" Not On Hold"; status=Gridview1.row[8].cell[8].Findcontrol("lblstats").tostring();

Comment: instead of doing this you cna directly get status of tender from single query while binding Gridview first time on page load.

Comment: why not just include this data in the original query used to bind the GridView?